# How can I return a query object in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

How can I return all results of `yii\db\Query` as an object from a query like this one?

```
$query = new Query;
$query->select('id, name')
      ->from('user')
      ->limit(10);
$rows = $query->all();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
 use yii\db\Query;

 $query = new Query;
 // compose the query
 $query->select('id, name')
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10);
 // build and execute the query
 $rows = $query->all();

 // accessing the value 
 foreach ($rows as $row){
    echo $row['name'];
  }
```

for accessing via $row->name;

try with

```
use common\models\User;  // or you app or backend depend where you have models
$rows = User::find()->limit(10)->all();

foreach ($rows as $row){
   echo $row->nome;

}
```

Comment: Yes this is as array. I want to get value like this `$row->name` due to large amounts of code I have already in another framework using objects.

Comment: If you want get the value like $row->name you can use activeQuery. Your question is about query i Have update the answer

Comment: I will use ActiveQuery.